# How to calculate the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_q}/\mathbb F_q)$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to calculate the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_q}/\mathbb F_q)$, where $\mathbb F_q$ is the finite field with $q$ elements and $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$ its algebraic closure, any hints or elegant answers? Really need help, thanks.

Comment: It's the cofiltered limit (also known as the inverse limit) of the Galois groups $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^n}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ which is the profinite integers $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: If $a_n$ is a sequence of integers that converges modulo every $k$ then $$\sigma(c)=\lim_{n\to \infty} c^{q^{a_n}}$$ is an automorphism and they are all of this form.

Comment: What the others are saying is the following. If $\sigma$ is an element of that Galois group, then its restriction to the subfield $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ is some power $F^{a_n}$ of the Frobenius automorphism, $0\le a_n<n$. Because $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$ is the union of those fields, $\sigma$ is fully determined when we know all the integers $a_n$. The catch is that whenever $n\mid m$ we have that $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}\subset \Bbb{F}_{q^m}$, and the corresponding powers of Frobenius need to agree, resulting in the requirement $a_m\equiv a_n\pmod n$ whenever $n\mid m$.

Comment: (cont'd) The end result of that system of congruences is a bit messy. It turns out that there are uncountably many automorphisms altogether.